# .NET service can't connect to Redis

Tags: .net, docker, redis, network-programming

I'm trying to get a .NET API to be able to connect to a Redis instance on my docker network. Here's what I've got:

- Redis container: up and running on custom docker network `my-network` at `localhost:6379`
- .NET service: trying to get up and running on custom docker network `my-network`

(Maybe?) Relevant versioning:

- Abp.RedisCache 5.4.0
- StackExchange.Redis 2.1.58

I've tried everything, `network inspect`, adding and removing both containers to the network, even with the special connection string flag `resolveDns=true` in my .NET code. No matter what I do I get:

```
StackExchange.Redis.RedisConnectionException: It was not possible to connect to the redis server(s). UnableToConnect on localhost:6379/Interactive, Initializing/NotStarted, last: NONE, origin: BeginConnectAsync, outstanding: 0, last-read: 0s ago, last-write: 0s ago, keep-alive: 60s, state: Connecting, mgr: 10 of 10 available, last-heartbeat: never, global: 0s ago, v: 2.1.58.34321
```

I'm losing my mind here, Redis is up and running at `localhost:6379` on the docker network, why can't .NET connect?

YES I've passed a custom redis.conf which has `bind 0.0.0.0` as well.

Comment: your Redis instance is not running at `localhost`. It has it's own IP address on the docker network.

Comment: YES! Thank you so much! Ugh, why does EVERY tutorial say `localhost`, even when using docker? Is there a way to specify what IP docker will assign or change this later? (Just for CI / CD concerns and predictability)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to Hans Kilian's comment, I was able to finally connect!

Despite what seemingly infinite Redis + Docker tutorials say on the using `localhost:6379`, this is in fact *not* the case when Redis is running in a Docker network. To find that IP, for example with a container named `redis`, issue:

```sh
docker inspect -f '{{range.NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' redis
```

**It is then the resulting IP address, with port 6379, that you would need to provide as your connection string.**

tl;dr;

not:

`localhost:6379`

but the Docker assigned IP for the container, ex.:

`172.18.0.7:6379`

EDIT: You can also use the container name instead of the IP, i.e.:

`redis:6379`

Hope this helps anyone who may stumble upon this.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create docker-compose.yml file with *links*

```yaml
    version: '3.4'
    
    services:
      caching:
        image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}caching
        build:
          context: .
          dockerfile: Caching/Dockerfile
        depends_on:
        - redis_cache
        links:
        - redis_cache
       
      redis_cache:
        image: "redis:latest"    
        container_name: cache
        ports:
            - '6379:6379'
```

2. Instead of localhost use the redis_cache name

```json
"ConnectionStrings": {
  "redis": "redis_cache:6379"
}
```